# Typescript in vue - Property 'validate' does not exist on type 'Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I created `v-form` like this

```html
<v-form ref="form" v-model="valid" lazy-validation>
   <!-- form content -->
   <v-btn
     :disabled="!valid"
     @click="submit"
   >
     Submit
   </v-btn>
</v-form>
```

script:

```js
if (this.$refs.form.validate()) // Error is in here
```

If i just `console.log(this.$ref.form)` the validate() function is available. But why this error is coming while building?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

### Solutions:

Simple:

```
(this.$refs.form as Vue & { validate: () => boolean }).validate()
```

Alternative *(use this if you reference `this.$refs.form` multiple times in your component)*:

```
computed: {
  form(): Vue & { validate: () => boolean } {
    return this.$refs.form as Vue & { validate: () => boolean }
  }
} // Use it like so: this.form.validate()
```

Reusable *(use this if you use the `v-form` component multiple times across your application)*:

```
// In a TS file
export type VForm = Vue & { validate: () => boolean }

// In component, import `VForm`
computed: {
  form(): VForm {
    return this.$refs.form as VForm
  }
}
```

---

### Explanation:

In the `Vue` template syntax, we can use the `ref` attribute on a `Vue` instance or a DOM element. If `ref` is used in a `v-for` loop, an array of `Vue` instances or DOM elements is retreived.

This is why `this.$refs` can either return `Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]`.

In order for `TypeScript` to know which type is being used, we need to cast the value.

We can either do:

`(this.$refs.form as Vue).validate()` or `(<Vue>this.$refs.form).validate()`

We cast it to `Vue` because `v-form` is a `Vue` instance (component) and not an `Element`.

My personal preference is to create a computed property which returns the `Vue` instance(s) or DOM element(s) already casted.

ie.

```
computed: {
  form(): Vue {
    return this.$refs.form as Vue
  }
}
```

---

The `v-form` instance has a `validate` method that returns a boolean, so we need to use an intersection type literal:

```
computed: {
  form(): Vue & { validate: () => boolean } {
    return this.$refs.form as Vue & { validate: () => boolean }
  }
}
```

Then we can use it like so: `this.form.validate()`

---

A better solution would be to create a type with the intersection so that it can be reused across multiple components.

```
export type VForm = Vue & { validate: () => boolean }
```

Then import it in the component:

```
computed: {
  form(): VForm {
    return this.$refs.form as VForm
  }
}
```

Comment: This still throwing an error, i dont know why. But if i use `(this.$refs.form as any).validate()` . if i give **Vue** as type it is not working but replace with **any** is working. why it is like that?

Comment: The thing is that the `Vue` interface does not have a `validate` method. That method is only declared in the `v-form` vue instance. I do not know what vuetify recommends or if they have types, basically there should be a `V-Form` interface that extends the `Vue` instance, letting `TypeScript` know which methods exist in that particular component.

Comment: @Sam An alternative is that you do something like: `(this.$refs.form as Vue & { validate: () => boolean }).validate()`

Comment: Thanks yar, it works. can you explain a bit about this `(this.$refs.form as Vue & { validate: () => boolean }).validate()` . How it is working?

Comment: What is the best way? `(this.$refs.form as any).validate()` or `(this.$refs.form as Vue & { validate: () => boolean }).validate()`

Answer (score 18):

If you use `vue-class-component` with `vue-property-decorator` you can do it like this:

Define in a `types.ts` a new Type with the vuetify form functions:

```
export type VForm = Vue & {
  validate: () => boolean;
  resetValidation: () => boolean;
  reset: () => void;
};
```

Then import in your component:

```
import { VForm } from "types";
import { Component, Ref} from "vue-property-decorator";
```

Use @Ref in your component to define the form:

```
export default class YourComponent extends Vue {
  @Ref("form") readonly form!: VForm;
}
```

so in your methods you can use it like this:

```
this.form.validate();
this.form.resetValidation();
this.form.reset();
```

Comment: This deserves more than the +1 I gave you!!

Comment: Great to hear that it helped you! If you want, feel free to donate me some coffee ;) https://ko-fi.com/gander

Answer (score 6):

```
let form: any = this.$refs.form
if(form.validate){}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I'm afraid it is also a terrible suggestion. This just disables the type checks... which is the whole point of TypeScript.

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers did it. I was trying to get the validate then promise to work on a form.

As per [comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/94#issuecomment-427645553)

if you are building your vue component in typescript using

```js
export default Vue.extend({})
```

then do

```js
import { ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider, extend } from "vee-validate";
import { required } from "vee-validate/dist/rules";
import Vue, { VueConstructor } from "vue";
export default (Vue as VueConstructor<
  Vue & {
    $refs: {
      form: InstanceType<typeof ValidationProvider>;
    };
  }
>).extend({
  methods: {
    saveEntity() {
      if (this.loading) return;
      console.log(this.entity);
      this.$refs.form.validate().then(success => {
        if (!success) {
          console.log("not valid");
          return;
        }
        console.log("valid");
      });
    }
  }
})
```

This validates the ValidationObserver ref="form" just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't comment on the accepted solution since I'm new to StackOverflow and wanted to provide my solution to this. I took the same initial step to investigate as OP and did a `console.log(this.$ref.form)`, the output on the console is actually an array of [VueComponent] and `validate()` function doesn't exist in that context.

I was able to access the `validate()` function on the form by doing `this.$ref.form[0].validate()`

Answer (score 1):

For vue 3 with Typescript the following worked for me:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { VForm } from 'vuetify/components'
import { ref } from 'vue';

const form = ref(VForm); // here I just put the type of the form. 

const logUser = async () => {
  const { valid } = await form.value.validate()
  console.log("The form is:", valid);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).