# Vuetify calendar in typescript class based component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to set up a calendar just like [the one on vuetify's page](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/calendars/usage.vue)

Only difference is that I am using class-components in typescript instead of javascript.

I am getting the errors on calls to `this.$refs.calendar.some_function`
 which are [included in the documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/calendars)

> Property 'getFormatter' does not exist on type 'Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]'.
>     Property 'getFormatter' does not exist on type 'Vue'.
>
> Property 'prev' does not exist on type 'Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]'.
>     Property 'prev' does not exist on type 'Vue'.
>
> Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]'.
>     Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Vue'.

as well as a wide variety of errors in console in the browser, for example:

> Property or method "setToday" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

I get these for every function. Perhaps caused by that there are compiling errors in the typescript?

The template looks exactly like the one on their page, and my class looks like this(with some functions removed that aren't affected by error):

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';

@Component
export default class AboutComponent extends Vue {
  private today: string = '2019-01-08';
  private focus: string = '2019-01-08';
  private type: string = 'month';
  private typeToLabel: any = {
    month: 'Month',
    week: 'Week',
    day: 'Day'
  };
  private start: any = null;
  private end: any = null;
  private selectedEvent: any = {};
  private selectedElement: any = null;
  private selectedOpen: boolean = false;
  private events: any[] = []; // Same events as on their page

  private get title () {
    const { start, end } = this;
    if (!start || !end) {
      return '';
    }

    const startMonth: any = this.monthFormatter(start);
    const endMonth: any = this.monthFormatter(end);
    const suffixMonth: any = startMonth === endMonth ? '' : endMonth;

    const startYear: any = start.year;
    const endYear: any = end.year;
    const suffixYear: any = startYear === endYear ? '' : endYear;

    const startDay: string = start.day + this.nth(start.day);
    const endDay: string = end.day + this.nth(end.day);

    switch (this.type) {
      case 'month':
        return `${startMonth} ${startYear}`;
      case 'week':
        return `${startMonth} ${startDay} ${startYear} - ${suffixMonth} ${endDay} ${suffixYear}`;
      case 'day':
        return `${startMonth} ${startDay} ${startYear}`;
    }
    return '';
  }

  private get monthFormatter () {
    return this.$refs.calendar.getFormatter({
      timeZone: 'UTC', month: 'long'
    });
  }

  private prev () {
    this.$refs.calendar.prev();
  }

  private next () {
    this.$refs.calendar.next();
  }
}
</script>
```

How do I make TypeScript aware that these functions exist on that type? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52109471/typescript-in-vue-property-validate-does-not-exist-on-type-vue-element/52109899#52109899)

I added the following to my code:

```
private get calendarInstance (): Vue & { prev: () => void, next: () => void,
    getFormatter: (format: any) => any } {
      return this.$refs.calendar as Vue & { prev: () => void, next: () => void, getFormatter: (format: any) => any };
    }
```

And changed my functions that references `this.$refs.calendar` to

```
private get monthFormatter (): any {
  return this.calendarInstance.getFormatter({
    timeZone: 'UTC', month: 'long'
  });
}

private prev (): void {
  this.calendarInstance.prev();
}

private next (): void {
  this.calendarInstance.next();
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem like you. I reworked the whole events example from vuetify for typescript: https://gist.github.com/Nicklas2751/da1fbe81878df7bb531fa4978c0ce7a8