# Problem with $refs and .nativeView on vue-property-decorator

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, vue-property-decorator

here is my code:

```html
<template>
  <Frame actionBarVisibility="never"> 
    <Page @loaded="init()" backgroundSpanUnderStatusBar="true">

        <GridLayout ref="root" >
             <Label class="message" text="some text" />
        </GridLayout>

    </Page>
  </Frame>
</template>
```

and this:

```js
<script lang="ts">

import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class Init extends Vue {
    init () {
       this.$refs.root.nativeView.backgroundColor = "#fff";
    }
}
</script>
```

the Problem:

ts complains about `.nativeView` after `$refs` :

`Property 'nativeView' does not exist on type 'Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]'.`

it seems that changing `this.$refs.root` to `( this.$refs.root as any )` solves the problem.

But is there any better approach? or could you please let me know why ts can Not apply `.nativeView` on the element (this.$refs.root) by himself?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56347690/7499991) should help you.

Comment: Take a look at the explanation section of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52109899/4305494).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but none of these links could solve my problem, and still I need to use `any` to remove the error.

Comment: @Tony actually it seems that the problem is related to .nativeView:
post UPDTAED!